How can I create a new record, presenting a standard layout and without navigating from the current page?
I am trying to create a lightning button.
Upon clicking the button, the standard new record page of the entity must open in dialog box rather than in a new tab. I tried the below code but it requires a pre-existing record Id since its action name is edit. Will it be possible to open new record page in a similar way?
openNewRecordDialog(){
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'ProductCatalog',
            recordId: recordid,   // Replace with your object's API name
            actionName: 'edit'
        }
    });
}


